# return const auto object -- and Qt implicit sharing

Tags: c++, qt, copy-on-write

So it is known this code is not sensical:

```
const int foo() 
{
  int n = // do computation...;
  return n;
}
```

Because what meaning is to return "const int" when it is copied anyway?

But with classes with implicit sharing (COW) like Qt containers, it makes sense again? Consider:

```
const QList<mytype> get_list()
{
   QList<mytype> lst;
   // do stuff to fill list;
   return lst;
}
```

Now I can do:

```
   const QList<mytype> mylst = get_list();
```

Since Qt has implicit sharing for containers, it should work OK because `return lst` doesn't really copy the contents of list, just increase refcount, and `const` make sure I can't modify it (if `get_list` want to ensure it for some reason, or needs it to be `const` method itself). Is my thinking correct here?

Comment: @Dennis: I'm basically asking whether all assumptiosn I listed in the question are correct

Answer (score 1):

> and const make sure I can't modify it ... Is my thinking correct here?

I couldn't understand the whole question. But, above part is not correct. You are returning just a `const` value from the function and it **doesn't mandate** the receiving end also to be a `const`. So removing `const` from `mylst` is allowed and it again becomes modifiable.

```
/* const */ QList<mytype> mylst = get_list();  // ok! 'mylst' is modifiable
```

Comment: Why is this so? Why isn't const mandated on the receiving end?

Comment: @zaharpopov, as you demonstrated for `const int` can be copied to `int` and be modified. Same rule applies here also. If you want make it non-modifiable then you may have to overload its copy-constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @zaharpopov: Copy construction (in most cases) takes a `const` reference (in this case your `const QList<mytype>&`) and creates a new object, which can be `const` or not.